# Two hyphens or one?

Tags: hyphenation

Should I leave out the first hyphen? Which one is correct -- "reading-comprehension-based testing" or "reading comprehension-based testing"?

Comment: To an intelligent outsider, _reading comprehension-based testing_ as in 'Yesterday, I was reading comprehension-based testing is a major tool in ...' is certainly a valid reading, and the possibility should be pre-empted. I'd certainly use both hyphens if forced to use the term. If it's a common term in education, I'm surprised RCBT isn't available: the initialism couldn't be wrongly parsed.

Comment: 1) Thank you for hyphenating at all! and 2) If possible, another structure might be less unwieldy—"Testing based on reading comprehension" etc (Also, yes, +1 for "all the hyphens")